# Why submitlist didn't show the list when run the app? [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am trying to display recyclerview list data using adapter. So far there is no error and I think my code logic is correct, but it didn't show the list when I run the app.

Below is my MainActivity code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(activityMainBinding.root)
    setSupportActionBar(activityMainBinding.mainToolbar)
    binding = activityMainBinding.contentMain

    val rv = binding.recyclerView
    val clickListener = { view: View, bandName:String ->
        //Deal with click feature later, show the list first
    }
    adapter = RVAdapter(clickListener)
    rv.adapter = adapter
    rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    adapter.submitlist(bandResources.values.toMutableList())
```

Below is my RVAdapter code

```
class RVAdapter(private val clickListener: (view:View, bandName: String)->Unit)
    : ListAdapter<BandInfo,RVAdapter.ViewHolder>(Diff())
{    
    inner class ViewHolder(val bandRowBinding : BandRowBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bandRowBinding.root) {
        init {
            bandRowBinding.root.setOnClickListener{
                //Deal with click feature later, show the list first
            }
        }
    }    
    private var bands = mutableListOf<BandInfo>()   
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val bandRowBinding = BandRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(bandRowBinding)
    }    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val binding = holder.bandRowBinding
        bands[position].let{
            binding.bandTitle.text = it.name
            binding.bandCreated.text = it.time
        }
    }    
    fun submitlist(items: MutableList<BandInfo>){
        bands = items
    }
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: This can be helpful https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/adapting-to-listadapter-341da4218f5b

Answer (score 1):

When using `ListAdapter`, you don't need to store the Band list in adapter.

And you don't need to declare another `submitlist` function because ListAdapter already had it, just simply call `submitList()` function from `ListAdapter` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your RecyclerView Adapter is implementing a `ListAdapter` which already handles the internal list and its `submitList` method for you.
By adding the `bands` list inside the adapter and adding your `submitList` method you are not using what is provided by the `ListAdapter` and hence your RecyclerView will show you nothing as the internal state of the adapter will always have an empty list.

Remove `bands` from the adapter and your submitList method. If you want to access the internal list of your adapter you can use `currentList` as a replacement of `bands`.

Answer (score 0):

You've added a `submitlist` method to `ListAdapter`, whereas `ListAdapter` has its own `submitList` method.

> I think my code logic is correct, but it didn't show the list

Your `submitlist` is assigning a new list to `bands`, but you're never notifying the adapter about it. You can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after assigning list to `bands`, It would start showing your list in the recyclerview.

```
fun submitlist(items: MutableList<BandInfo>){
    bands = items
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

---

> Using `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not efficient

`notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't tell the `reyclerView` what data is changed, and it forces to recreate the whole list, that is not efficient. We should always use specific notify methods like `notifyItemChanged`, `notifyItemInserted` and `notifyItemRemoved`. So, `recyclerView` have to draw only the required changes.

`ListAdapter` has its own `submitList` method which takes a new list and uses provided `diff` implementation to display it in the `recyclerView`. It takes care of notifying process and only calls the required methods by comparing the old and new list using the provided `diff` implementation.

You've to make a few changes for in your `RVAdapter` for your `adapter` to work.

```
class RVAdapter(private val clickListener: (view:View, bandName: String)->Unit)
    : ListAdapter<BandInfo, RVAdapter.ViewHolder>(Diff())
{    
    inner class ViewHolder(val bandRowBinding : BandRowBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bandRowBinding.root) {
        init {
            bandRowBinding.root.setOnClickListener{
                //Deal with click feature later, show the list first
            }
        }
    }    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val bandRowBinding = BandRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(bandRowBinding)
    }    

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val binding = holder.bandRowBinding
        getItem(position).let{ //use `getItem` method of ListAdapter to get current item
            binding.bandTitle.text = it.name
            binding.bandCreated.text = it.time
        }
    }        
}
```